# Vibrate notification only on wearable device

Tags: android, wear-os

Is it possible to do a vibrate notification on a wearable device but without set any sound or vibration on the phone? I want to allow to vibrate the watch but not the phone. There is a settings in the android wear app but it's a general settings and not app specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply used a silent.mp3 file and I set it as notification sound :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you just create notification on the Wear device itself (use Message API to trigger it), and it will be shown only on the smartwatch, so if you set vibrations for it - only smartwatch will vibrate.

Comment: I agree with you but I found a very simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is not similar feature in Android. Developer reference doesn't provide any information about function you described. I think, you should suggest user to decide about vibrations and notifications.

Answer (score -1):

1. you must set permision in Androidmanifest.xml

   uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"
2. Add Code (I have a button when you click on phone, A notification and vibrate will active on watch)

   ```
       Button wearButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.wearButton);
        wearButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {

           int notificationId = 001;
           Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_background);
           NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle style = new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle();
           style.bigPicture(bitmap);



           //big image
           NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
                   new NotificationCompat.Builder(MainActivity.this)

                   .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.baby)
                   .setContentTitle("Title")
                   .setContentText("Android Wear Notification");
           notificationBuilder.setStyle(style);

           //Vibration
           notificationBuilder.setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000});

           //Ton
          // notificationBuilder.setSound(R.);

           NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager =
                   NotificationManagerCompat.from(MainActivity.this);
           notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notificationBuilder.build());
       }
   });
   ```

I have a complete project if you wan you can download 
https://app.box.com/s/veb68n0uzxcmotyo0rmfrxgyoig032lc